# Join string and quantities

Tags: dataset

How can I join a string and a quantity and still preserved the quantity format?
This what I have achieved:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
          <|"Column 1 of Quantities" -> 
         "Quantity number 1:" Quantity[10, "Meters"]|>,
       <|"Column 1 of Quantities" -> 
         "Quantity number 1:" Quantity[17, "Meters"]|>,
       <|"Column 1 of Quantities" -> 
         "Quantity number 1:" Quantity[16, "Meters"]|>,
       <|"Column 1 of Quantities" -> 
         "Quantity number 1:" Quantity[12, "Meters"]|>,
       <|"Column 1 of Quantities" -> 
         "Quantity number 1:" Quantity[22, "Meters"]|>,
       <|"Column 1 of Quantities" -> 
         "Quantity number 1:" Quantity[2, "Meters"]|>}]
```

Beacuse what I get is the string, but with the quantity in parenthesis.

Comment: replace `Quantity number 1:"  Quantity[10, "Meters"]` with `Row[{"Quantity number 1:", Quantity[10, "Meters"]}]` or with `StringRiffle[{"Quantity number 1:", Quantity[10, "Meters"]}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Row[{"Quantity number 1:", Quantity[10, "Meters"]}]` or `StringRiffle[{"Quantity number 1:", Quantity[10, "Meters"]}]` instead of `Quantity number 1:"  Quantity[10, "Meters"]` when you define `dataset`. (Similarly, for other entries.)

If `dataset` is already define as in OP, you can use `ReplaceAll` to replace `Times` with `Row` or with `StringRiffle` as follows:

```
dataset /. Times -> (StringRiffle[{##}] &)
```

[image]

```
dataset /. Times -> (Row[{##}] &)
```

[image]

Comment: Both seems pretty good answers.